# Google Sheets Query: Select A,B,E WHERE E MATCHES X OR E MATCHES Y OR E MATCHES Z

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

So I have the following query:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:J,"SELECT A,B,E WHERE E MATCHES 'UK > Maternity Leave' OR E MATCHES 'UK > Long Leave' OR E MATCHES 'UK > Career Break' OR E MATCHES 'UK > Extended Unpaid Leave' OR WHERE E MATCHES 'UK > Shared Parental Leave (Birth)'",1)
```

Which, as far as I can tell should work. But it is giving me the following error message:

> Error
> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
> PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "where" "WHERE "" at line 1, column 162.
> Was expecting one of: "true" ... "false" ... "not" ... "date" ...
> "timeofday" ... "datetime" ... "timestamp" ... "min" ... "max" ...
> "avg" ... "count" ... "sum" ... "no_values" ... "no_format" ... "is"
> ... "null" ... "year" ... "month" ... "day" ... "hour" ... "minute"
> ... "second" ... "millisecond" ... "with" ... "contains" ... "starts"
> ... "ends" ... "matches" ... "like" ... "now" ... "dateDiff" ...
> "quarter" ... "lower" ... "upper" ... "dayOfWeek" ... "toDate" ...
>  ... <INTEGER_LITERAL> ... <DECIMAL_LITERAL> ... <STRING_LITERAL>
> ... <QUOTED_ID> ... "(" ... "-" ...

Here is a link to the sheet - [SO Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M4N1hHiNPZ0xlJInSZ_r8nDmAaouB3mH1MFqrSJPAHA/edit#gid=520617162)

I can't see what I am doing wrong here. I have tried `SELECT A, B, E` and `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col5` as I have had some weird errors with queries in sheets in the past due to that. If anyone can point out what is wrong, that would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `WHERE` listed more than once, which looks like the issue.

Instead:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:J,"SELECT A,B,E WHERE E MATCHES 'UK > Maternity Leave' OR E MATCHES 'UK > Long Leave' OR E MATCHES 'UK > Career Break' OR E MATCHES 'UK > Extended Unpaid Leave' OR E MATCHES 'UK > Shared Parental Leave (Birth)'",1)
```

Comment: Ahh, somehow I didn't see that! Ahaha. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No worries - an easy mistake we all do.